# Download the second half of a video using http's Range header

Tags: python, video, download, mp4

I want to download the second half of a video I have on my local host, I wrote some python code to download the file starting from the half to the end(via http's Range header)

but when I open the file with vlc, nothing happens(so it doesn't work)

how can I download a part of a mp4 file and still be able to watch it?

```
import urllib2

file_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/vid.mp4'

result = urllib2.urlopen(file_url)
cont_len = result.headers['content-length']
req = urllib2.Request(file_url)
req.headers['Range'] = 'bytes=%s-%s' % (str(int(int(cont_len) / 2)), str(int(cont_len)))

f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File = open('2ndhalf.mp4', 'w')
File.write(f.read())
```

**Edit: my intention is to download videos the part of the videos faster, and not to download the whole video and then cut it**

Comment: @falsetru is there anyway I can make a header for the mp4 file?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to download the complete `moov`. From there you can get the offset to the middle frame, You can then download for that frame to end (assuming the frames are in order, Likely, but not required by mp4). Next rewrite the `moov` using only the entries you wish to keep, and make sure all the offsets are adjusted to match the new chunks offsets.

Comment: I edited my question, my intention is to not download the complete vid, part of what I'm doing is to keep things as fast as possible

Comment: That doesn't change the answer. the`mdat` is useless without the `moov`

Comment: Start downloading from the beginning, while looking for the `moov`. If its not there, you can skip over boxes by canceling the http request, and making a new one. Its not possible to do what you are asking without making several requests, seeking within the file.

Comment: Based on your response, I'm guessing you don't know how mp4s are structured, there is a data part (`mdat`) and a header/index part (`moov`) You need the COMPLETE `moov` to read the `mdat`. The `moov` of fairly small, It may be before or after the `mdat`. You need to get that first.

Comment: thanks so much, I could solve it simple by using ffmpeg :/
`ffmpeg -ss 544.81 -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/vid.mp4 -t 6.99 -c:v copy -c:a copy vid_part.mp4;`

Comment: @AbdallahSamman That works because FFmpeg is making a new `moov` header from cropped file's remaining frames. You could have just copied the original existing one. But if FFmpeg works for you... The `moov` contains info like picture size, frame rate, positions of keyframes, etc (things that are needed to correctly play the video). That's why VLC could not play without the info.

Comment: @VC.One I was wondering is it possible to fetch some key-frames of a video from web server by the HTTP Range header? For example, for a 30 seconds duration video, we'd like to analysis the I-frame around 00:00:02, 00:00:15, 00:00:28.

Comment: @pvd If you have a new question. Open a new question. DO not ask new questions in comments.

Comment: @szatmary For sure, thanks for your kind reminder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209408/is-it-possible-to-fetch-some-key-frames-of-a-video-by-using-the-http-range-heade

Comment: @pvd - were you able to solve the last part of your question?? ```For example, for a 30 seconds duration video, we'd like to analysis the I-frame around 00:00:02, 00:00:15, 00:00:28.```