# Getting certain frames from a video online without downloading it locally

Tags: python, url, video

I have a bunch of urls pointing to online videos. All of them are really massive having size over 1 GB and I need certain frames from those. For instance I need say five random frames from time 1000 to 1200 seconds. Is there a way for me to get this without downloading the entire thing?

I know I can do

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, video_name)
```

in python and then do whatever I need to do. But this obviously downloads the entire thing which is what I am trying to avoid. If this is not possible with python, is there some other way I can do this for example with MATLAB or similar?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the resource. Is it an mp4 file or what? With HTML5 video, you can send requests for particular bytes of the video... That is how browsers seek/buffer video. Maybe look there.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42470133/334402